Excel copy Conditional formatting
I have an excel conditional format which perfectly in a row. But for some reason when I copy to the row below it does not change the formula as I expected. I am using formula only rather than a standard paste and making sure the formula does not have an extra $ in it so it is not a static reference. See image of formula. I have tried many things but cannot see why this would not copy and change the formula when moving to different rows.
Basically if cell contains text Yr2 and cell on same row is greater than 90 it goes green. This works fine but when going to next row I am expecting E3 to change to E4 and C3 to change to C4.
Condtional formula in E3 is
=IF(AND(E3>=90,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("YR2",C3))),TRUE, FALSE)


Please just copy formula and paste into your question as text.

First, you don't need the IF() part of your formula. Try selecting the range where the conditional formula should be applied, then add the conditional formatting formula, pressing F2 for edit mode, and then F4 to toggle the $ as needed.

When you created the conditional format in one cell:

Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules
Select the rule you want to apply on other cells
In the Apply to: textbox type or select the required range.
Click Apply and OK/Close



Thanks for this. I did do this and it was not working but realised there was another rule that was causing an issue. This confirmed what I was doing was correct which let me to other issue
